# How to manage multiple API calls in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to manage multiple calls to an API. I am having an array of data and each element of array is used while calling an API and response is echoed back. The architecture goes following way:

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);//Did as loop takes >30s
    require_once 'other/VirusTotalApiV2.php';
    $obj= new VirusTotalAPIV2("abc");//Forming object of API
    $handle=fopen("foo.txt","r"); // Obtaining the elements    

    while($read=fgets($handle))//Each line stores an element
    {
    $counter=0;
    $report=$obj->getFileReport($read);//Calling API function
    //var_dump($report);
    echo "<table>
        <tr>
        <td>Antivirus</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Update</td>
        </tr>";
    foreach($report->scans as $key=>$value){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
        echo "<td>".result($value->result)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$value->update."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $counter++;
    }
}
echo $counter;
fclose($handle);
function result($input){
    if($input==null)
    {
        return "No Issue";
    }
}
```

Can I increase the efficiency of this calling as currently, the final output is receieved(at once) after 10s-15s and till that time page keeps loading. 
Please suggest some better way out.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  How is this not working as expected?  It doesn't seem particularly inefficient from the looks of the code.

Comment: @David I have pasted the original code. As I execute this code, it returns result in more than 10s. Till that time, the page keeps loading. I want to get rid of this as I want to do it on large scale when there will be more than 100 elements.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be happening in a background process, not when loading a page.  Long-running processes shouldn't block the UI.

Comment: @David even if I use ajax calls, it will be taking place in background but still it will take 10-15s to return back the data. My concern is to improve effeciency of calling API to get faster results.

Comment: If the `curl_multi` suggestion below doesn't do the trick, you might need to use threads: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the HTTP client is in use, but assuming its a wrapper of cURL you could look at [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php).

> Allows the processing of multiple cURL handles asynchronously.